# Unable to find the socket transport "ssl", CakePHP sending e-mail from shell

Tags: shell, cakephp, cron, openssl, wamp

I am trying to send an e-mail from a cron using CakePHP shell but I am getting the following error "Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you  configured PHP?: 0".

The problem is on local server only, I am using WAMP server and the php_openssl extension is correctly turned on. When I checked if the extension is being loaded from a controller everything seems fine but when I debug the shell action, the extension doesn't seem to be loaded. Furthermore when I try to send an e-mail from a controller, the e-mail is successfully sent. I am using gmail credentials thus the ssl requirement.

Thanks

Comment: T'would be helpful to see the code, especially the socket connection.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solution found, it seems that you have to uncomment the line where the openssl extension can be found in (path to wamp)\bin\php(your php version)\php.ini since there are 2 php.ini files, enabling it only in the (path to wamp)\bin\apache(apache version)\bin\php.ini is not enough

Comment: Yes, it works for me. Obviously you need to change both files.

Answer (score 1):

You need setting for php and apache

> ```
> Check ssl_module in the Apache modules.
> Check php_openssl in the PHP extensions.
> ```