# apns not connecting in php

Tags: php, ssl, notifications, apple-push-notifications

i am new to push notifications and tried following to fix this but it still gives same error.

1. added C:\PHP\ext to the Windows path
2. added libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll to C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv
3. rebooted the server

first error:-

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ApnsPHP_Exception' with message 'Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195': Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (0)' in C:\wamp\www\ApnsPHP-master\ApnsPHP\Abstract.php on line 396

second error:-

> ApnsPHP_Exception: Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195': Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (0) in C:\wamp\www\ApnsPHP-master\ApnsPHP\Abstract.php on line 396

*i am using a .pem file which was used before somewhere else
and also i am trying to run my file on localhost, does it matter ?*

if someone knows something that what should i do to fix this error, then please help me !
and thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look if SSL is enabled in your configuration.

To display your configuration simply copy/paste the following in some php file and browse to it with a browser:

```
<?php
   phpInfo();
?>
```

Comment: thanx, i checked it,  
it showed as follows:-
SSL --> supported and OpenSSL support --> disabled (install ext/openssl) what should i do ?

Comment: according to [this site](http://rlabs.wordpress.com/2009/03/28/unable-to-find-the-socket-transport-ssl/) wamp might point to another `php.ini` file

Comment: if it isn't enabled, you should look for the lines for openssl and uncomment (also [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139528/unable-to-find-the-socket-transport-ssl-cakephp-sending-e-mail-from-shell))

Comment: firstly it didnt workred, then i removed ssl:// from *ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195*, then it worked.  
thanx saeros